# using turnjs inside angluarjs bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

i have done a modal service based on 
[dan wahlins blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service)

in this model i tried to use [turnjs](http://www.turnjs.com/) flip book by wrapping it in a angularjs custom directive. 
the directive code look like follows.

```
 mod.directive('flipBook', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/views/html/amlModule/kyc/flipModule.html',
        replace: true,
        compile: function (element, attrs) {

            element.bind('turning', function (event, page, obj) {
                console.log("page is : " + page);
            });

            element.turn({
                width: '200px',
                height: '200px',
                pages: 8
            }).turn('peel', 'br');

            element.addClass('flipbook');
        }
    }
});
```

template HTML is like below

```
<div>
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
</div>
```

when i use this as a seperate program , ie : when i include custom directive in a plain html bound to a angularjs app, it is working fine,

but when i am using it with bootstrap modal service i only get the first page of the book, no turning and interaction is allowed.

in Google chrome there are no errors regarding the matter,

i'm bit confused now, you guys have any suggestions to resolve this issue?

**ps : below is the image when i use the custom directive with the modal service.**

[image: test modal]

Comment: add a `plunker` link

Comment: A plunker link would be helpful here. Though to start off, try binding to the element in the directive's `link` function. It is then that the element is bound to the DOM and is ready to bind to. Right now you're in `compile`...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, the reason is turn.js is not called when you call the modal, you have two options 
1) put the turn.js related scripts in actual modal body
or
2) when you call the modal run the turn.js , so it will call the DOM.